# kafka streams stateful mode is error (rocksdb don't initialize)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

error code :

```
Failed to close task manager due to the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.rocksdb.DBOptions
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.TimestampedSegment.openDB(TimestampedSegment.java:49)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.TimestampedSegments.getOrCreateSegment(TimestampedSegments.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.TimestampedSegments.getOrCreateSegment(TimestampedSegments.java:25)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.AbstractSegments.getOrCreateSegmentIfLive(AbstractSegments.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.AbstractRocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.put(AbstractRocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:111)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:34)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.putAndMaybeForward(CachingWindowStore.java:106)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.lambda$initInternal$0(CachingWindowStore.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:151)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:109)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.flush(ThreadCache.java:124)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.flush(CachingWindowStore.java:291)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.flush(WrappedStateStore.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.lambda$flush$4(MeteredWindowStore.java:200)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:801)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.flush(MeteredWindowStore.java:200)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:282)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.suspend(StreamTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.close(StreamTask.java:745)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.closeTask(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.closeTask(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:37)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.shutdown(AssignedTasks.java:256)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.shutdown(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:535)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.shutdown(TaskManager.java:292)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.completeShutdown(StreamThread.java:1133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:682)
```

Local works fine.

In the environment where the error occurs, the error occurs when uploading it to docker.
kafka streams version : 2.5.0

Comment: Upload what to docker? Can you share your Dockerfile and code as a [mcve]?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.